# Android: How to disable enter key on multitext?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext

I want to create an edittext, multitext on android studio with max lines =3. But when i press enter it creates many lines and hides the content that i had written.

I want an edittext multitext that has max 3 lines and when i click enter it will not create more lines than 3.

Comment: https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-disable-keyboard-events-in-jtextarea/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set maximum input lines in android edit text.

```
   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/input_edit_text"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:inputType="textMultiLine"
       android:maxLines="3" />
```